# TypeLoadException in Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing

I'm writing a test when I create a User and give them a role, then check to make sure the role was given properly. I'm able to create the user, and assign roles, load the user into HttpContext.Current, and persist the user. However when I check to see if the roles have been assigned properly I get the following error.

```
An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load type 'MyProject.Repositories.RQRole' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

I have searched all over, there is no MyProject.exe but there is a MyProject debug database. The MyProject.dll is there and other tests that reference it can do it just fine.

This is the line that throws the error.

```
Assert.IsTrue(System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole("user"));
```

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.asp.net/t/1270044.aspx?Unit+Testing+the+Role+and+Membership+Providers

I specified the specific name of the dll and it worked just fine.